# jQuery Mobile- Landscape and Portrait Changes

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hello stackoverflow community, I just had a quick question regarding landscape and portrait viewing of images on the iphone or any mobile devices. You can head to this site http://dev1.affectdesign.com to view to problem I'm talking about, the site is incomplete and not as "pretty" as I'd like it yet. But it's coming along. When viewing on the iphone or android in portrait, the app looks how i want it to look image wise. However once you turn it to landscape the images say the same size and just align left. How can i get a static image to adjust to landscape and portrait? I am only proficient in the HTML side of Jquery. Javascript is not my forte by any means, so try to provide a simple solution.

(if the question is answered correctly and easily and viewed a lot, ill create a subdomain with the current site and code for if people want to view this problem later)

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
img {
   width: 100%;
}
```